# Targetting a specific wallet when sending commands using RPC commands to bitcoind

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I'm very new to Bitcoin development, using its RPC API.

I created a wallet using

```
{
    "method": "createwallet",
    "params": {
        "wallet_name": "/wallets/walletA"
    }
}
```

Now I want to get info about this wallet. I try to use the `getwalletinfo` command.

But it seems you can't specify the wallet *name*/*path* when running this command? You have to "load" the wallet first (using `loadwallet`)?

This is the part I do not understand. Let's say I have created 10 wallets and I try to run a `getwalletinfo` command in a multithreaded environment... How can I make sure I target the right wallet? Do I really have to send a `loadwallet` request to specify the wallet I want to work on, before getting info about it?

What will occure if I want to get information about "walletA" so I run `loadwallet walletA`, but before I can run `getwalletinfo` to get its info, a `loadwallet walletB` request is made?

Comment: did you find any solution . im stuck in sending transaction from the specific account address .

Answer (score 1):

When more than one wallet is available, the wallet is selected by sending the RPC requests to `<host:port>/wallet/<wallet_name>`.

You might have to play around with the exact form, I suspect it might be `<host:port>/wallet/wallets/walletA` in your case, or `<host:port>/wallets/walletA`, or `<host:port>/wallet/walletA`.

Comment: I have been unable to make this work. Maybe because I'm on Windows with backslahes in paths. I tried *everything*: url encoding, escaping backslahes, etc. I even looked at Bitcoin code, and I'm not sure paths are properly managed when following `/wallet/` in urls! In the end, I decided to use the `walletdir` config in `bitcoin.conf`in order to specify the directory where wallets will be created. And I only use the name of a wallet (no path) in the RPC `/wallet/[wallet_name]` url. This works. Hope it helps someone, one day.